# How to implement async/await in Dart

Tags: dart, dart-async

I think I understand the idea behind *async*, returning a Future, but I am not clear on how *async* behaves on a very basic level.  From my understanding, it does not automatically create asynchronous behavior in a program.  For example:

```
import 'dart:async';
main() {
  a();
  b();
}
a()  {
  new Timer(new Duration(milliseconds: 20), () {});  // create latency
  print("a");
}
b()  {
  print("b");
}
// a
// b
```

If you put *async* after the a(), the b() is executed first asynchronously, and a() executes after the given latency:

```
import 'dart:async';
main() {
  a();
  b();
}
a() **async** {
  new Timer(new Duration(milliseconds: 20), () {});  // create latency
  print("a");
}
b()  {
  print("b");
}
// b 
// a
```

But if you put *async* after both a() and b(), a() executes first, similar to not using *async* at all:

```
import 'dart:async';
main() {
a();
b();
}
a() **async** {
  new Timer(new Duration(milliseconds: 20), () {});  // create latency
  print("a");
}
b() **async** {
  print("b");
}
//a
//b
```

Is using *async* on all functions cancelling the *async* function completely?

Now, I think that the main() *async* does not actually activate the asynchronous behavior by itself.  If you add *async* after the main(), nothing changes.  However, it allows for you to use *await*, in case you must wait for the a() function to finish first, before you continue the program.  Is this right?

```
import 'dart:async';
main() **async** {
  **await** a();
  b();
}
a() **async** {
new Timer(new Duration(milliseconds: 20), () {});  // create latency
print("a");
}
b() {
print("b");
}
// waits for the value of a() if you put **await** keyword
// a
// b
```

However, I see main() *async* {} alot as well as using it after the script html tag, yet there is no *await* anywhere.  Does it mean different things in different contexts?  I hope I have explained the logic adequately.  Can you explain how I am misunderstanding the use of async/await?  Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
a()  {
  new Timer(new Duration(milliseconds: 20), () {});  // create latency
  print("a");
}
```

This code doesn't delay execution of `print("a");` for 20 ms. It just delays the execution of `{}` which is enqueued for later execution, and then immediately continued with `print("a");`

Your code using `async` / `await` and the equivalent code without `async` / `await` would look like:

```
import 'dart:async';
main() async {
  await a();
  b();

  await main2(); // call the example without async/await
}
Future a()  async {
  await new Future.delayed(const Duration(milliseconds: 20), () {});  // create latency
  print("a");
}
void b()  {
  print("b");
}

Future main2() {
  return a2().then((_) {
    b();
  }); 
}

// equivalent of a without async/await
Future a2()   {
  return new Future.delayed(const Duration(milliseconds: 20), () {})  // create latency
  .then((_) => print("a"));
}
```

Try on [DartPad](https://dartpad.dartlang.org/d0c673ae27df892849d5)

Comment: Thanks.  I was not aware that I was not truly creating a latency.  However, with your example, the only difference is that if you put async before both a() and b(), you get the printed b first, then a. I think my question may be too broad, so let me refine it to one particular case.  Why do you use main() async {}, when main() never really returns anything, since it is the starting function?  What does it actually do under main() when you don't have any subsequent need for an await?

Comment: "if you put async before both a() and b(), you get the printed b first," I don't understand what you mean by that, can you create a dartpad to demonstrate? `await a()` in main is to ensure that `b()` is not invoked before `b()` is completed. `await` is only allowed in functions marked `async`. `await` in `await main2();` doesn't have much of an effect, because it is the last statement in `main`.

Comment: What I meant may be better stated above.  Can you please see the original post and code where I wrote, "Is using async on all functions cancelling the async function completely?"  1) Can you explain why adding async to both a() and b() is causing the above behavior?  I don't get.  And (2) to be completely clear, I think you are saying that "main() async" does not (ever?) actually add anything if you do not use await.  And I would also conclude that in: script async type="application/dart" src="main.dart", the async does not truly add anything either.  Is that right?

Comment: 1)I don't really understand your questions. I thought I did explain the behavior. 2) `async`s only purpose is, to be able to use `await`. `async` isn't cancelling anything.

Comment: Oh cripes!  I get it now.  I actually misunderstood your first answer.  So, in the second code sample above, the `async` in `a() async` is actually creating a latency by itself, causing the entire function to delay (not just the `new Timer` as intended), thus printing the 'b' first.  In the third sample code, `b() async` has the same inherent latency given by the `async`, causing the 'a' to print first.  Thanks for your patience, and your help.